# How Do Optimize My Code for a Quad Core GPU?

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es-2.0, gpu

The current and previous iPad models use a quad-code GPU. Can someone please tell me how - as a 3D dev - I can take full advantage of the mult-core architecture. Is there anything special I need to be doing to see maximum performance?

Comment: How do I optimize my code for running on a toaster? (any context deliberately omitted)

Comment: Ok, I don't see anythign wrong with the question asked. Why has this guy been deprived of 8 reputation? Just trying to understand.

Comment: Um, huh? What on earth is wrong with this question? I accept the closing of this question with protest and find H2CO3, and the rest of this troll like crew to be outrageous and completely at odds with the spirit with which Joel and co created this service. Shame on you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing; it's an [abuse of the term "quad-core"](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/121993-apple-a5x-is-the-new-ipad-quad-core-or-not).

Desktop GPUs have dozens or hundreds of "processors" — vertex processors, shader processors, "stream processors" (multiple stream processors are often grouped into a single shader processor). This works because typical 3D rendering is inherently parallel: Vertices can be projected independently, pixels can typically be rendered independently for each stage, and adjacent pixels typically have neighbouring inputs (e.g. the same area of a texture) which makes caching easier. All of this is typically handled by the GPU.

You might need to do a little more reading and performance comparisons if you write your own pixel shaders, but this doesn't really depend on the number of "cores" — the constructs used in pixel shader languages tend to be parallelizable by default. (This doesn't mean it's not easy to write non-parallelizable code if you try, but unless you're trying to get poor performance you should be fine.)

Comment: Thanks a lot tc. I sorta had a feeling it was a non-starter.

Comment: Dude, why are you a member of the trolls that closed this question? I don't get it.